# Paypal REST Api with retrofit

Tags: android, rest, paypal, retrofit

I am trying to use Paypal REST api with retrofit, but i am getting the following error

```
{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"2689a7ff7bf28","details":[{"field":"/purchase_units","value":"","location":"body","issue":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","description":"A required field / parameter is missing."},{"field":"/intent","value":"","location":"body","issue":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","description":"A required field / parameter is missing."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","rel":"information_link","encType":"application/json"}]
```

here is the request body

```
Request{method=POST, url=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/?%2Fintent=CAPTURE&%2Fpurchase_units=%5B%7B%22currency_code%22%3A%22USD%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22100%22%7D%5D, tags={class retrofit2.Invocation=c.shobaky.tofahaway.orderRequest.Order() [application/json, Bearer A21AAJ-S4HTuRR7ip1zAflRxUBsIVeEkxAAVWM7ZEB7uvn8g-0GBk6Swa3gwWMIiQYBtsXUssvzKWHv6IHDHYIQjREv6ToYow, CAPTURE, [{"currency_code":"USD","value":"100"}]]}}
```

Here is the code

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
    orderRequest Order = retrofit.create(orderRequest.class);


    JSONArray Purchase = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject Amount = new JSONObject();
    try {
        Amount.put("currency_code","USD");
        Amount.put("value","100");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Purchase.put(Amount);


    Call<String> call = Order.Order("application/json","Bearer A21AAJ-S4HTuRR7ip1zAflRxUBsIVeEkxAAVWM7ZEB7uvn8g-0GBk6Swa3gwWMIiQYBtsXUssvzKWHv6IHDHYIQjREv6ToYow","CAPTURE",Purchase);
    call.enqueue(this);

}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
    try {
        Log.d("RESPONEPYPAL",call.request().toString()+response.errorBody().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

}
```

I got the access token using curl by passing the client id and secret id, so i am almost sure it isn't about the authorization, it looks like it has something to do with "intent" and "purchase unit"

UPDATE
i used this request before the previous one and also didn't work

```
{method=POST, url=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/, tags={class retrofit2.Invocation=c.shobaky.tofahaway.orderRequest.Order() [application/json, Bearer A21AAJQvfCFvMKkiWA9anZaEU_hBJ0Pb_TPOQtjqtCjFc39nc_rX6Y5RsCKoYbseMjgiCeGPMhyD5Omqw2tUlgh2EZT-9kiXQ, CAPTURE, [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"100"}}]]}}
```

Comment: The error message is "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema". so the error is at your end may be typo error or any param missing, try this request also with curl or postman and verify it once. if it works you can easily debug your request.

Comment: I am actually just translating the curl code from paypal documentation to Java :/

Comment: I did like you said,, i used the documentation curl code and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not only does your "request body" show a URL with query string parameters, which is wrong, but you are also sending an empty POST body to PayPal, which is where the well-formed JSON with a `purchase_units` array needs to be.

Comment: Yes sorry, for the query parameters, i was just debugging but i tried to send it encoded, for the purchase_units it has only required field which is 'amount' which has two required fields which i am sending but here in my question i forgot to include 'amount' in purhase array but i tried it although and didn't work

Comment: (1) You aren't sending any POST data to PayPal, at all -- only a blank string. (2) The data you are trying to send (but not actually sending yet ) is wrong, you need it to be like what is in the example at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create , including the key names.

Comment: Okey sorry but what are these fields then in my request? CAPTURE, [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"100"}}]

Comment: I have no idea, but they aren't being transmitted

Comment: How and when i used Query instead of Field annotation in the retrofit interface they appear in the url?! anyway i think i discovered the problem, maybe because it must be in one variable, i am trying to send them using Body annotation

Comment: Now my problem is that retrofit sends the class reference -_- Request{method=POST, url=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/, tags={class retrofit2.Invocation=c.shobaky.tofahaway.orderRequest.Order() [application/json, Bearer A21AALZqJhprXJGWTCFeBR_EPIx6CnkPSNtLpeSy5yhY3_eDU3wQ8_n4KjaVzounHcDf_nOzCaq63Kje5_nsp5xWiGK53amGA, c.shobaky.tofahaway.orderBody@c6bb624]

Comment: If you still interested in helping, i used the documentation curl code and doesn't work :/ it generates the same error!

Comment: Please show your curl command and error response received, that we can help with

Comment: curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAI0hY8mvFIKlrUOnc9iJikbrHUxWPYnrB11tGsQNMfKMZB_O3bxPlY46cdwLHRVMMYBlQ8BCu5DexIuPLNQkJfj_HzPAw" -d '{"intent": "CAPTURE" "purchase_units": [ {"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"100.00"}}]}'

Comment: And what's the error? That seems close to correct but it's not well-formed JSON, misisng a comma at the least

Comment: I am using exactly the same code in the official documentation {"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"91c5d029db201","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON"}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON","rel":"information_link","encType":"application/json"}]}* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact

Comment: Well at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create you will notice there is a comma after "CAPTURE".  Well-formed JSON is essential.

Comment: yes sorry you made me note the comma thanks , but now it tells me it cannot resovle host CAPTURE

Comment: Probably a quotation issue, e.g. terminating the single quotes (') of the -d early

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221195/discussion-between-moumenshobakey-and-preston-phx).

Answer (score 0):

cURL doesn't work properly in windows prompt, so i used power shell and worked well!